# Is there an alternative to SQL-Server's uniqueidentifer datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm migrating a login page from one server to another. The old server hosts an SQL-server database and the new one MySQL. The login page uses the guid from the user table to identify users with a session variable. Is there a similar alternative to use in MySQL?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PhpMyAdmin, this is a MySQL question

Comment: MySQL implementation may vary across platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a [universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) using the [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function:

```
mysql> select uuid();
bb2647fb-bed7-11e2-a78a-001f166db385
```

To store one of those you can use `CHAR(36)`.

Comment: Note that with InnoDB, the primary key gets included with every other index inside the same table; bigger primary keys -> bigger indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The standard MySQL way to create an unique ID (in that table) is with a `PRIMARY KEY` `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).